# Is WebRTC a good solution for file playback with OSD layer?

Tags: streaming, webrtc

Is WebRTC a good solution for implementing file playback with an OSD display?

I.e. The sending device streams the *.webm files sequentially (either using MediaStream or DataChannel) out p2p,
and then the receiving web browser displays the video and allows
the user to toggle on and off the OSD display?
(OSD layer can use same DataChannel that has the same PeerConnection
as the video stream's Mediastream/Datachannel.)

So, does this use case align very well as what WebRTC is intended for?

Comment: You essentially want to use WebRTC as a means to stream video from a server? Why all the connection establishment overhead? What advantage does that have over a straight HTTP-served video? I'm also unclear how that OSD plays into the question.

Comment: I would like for an embedded device (like a camera) to stream p2p and secure to a web browser.  For example, the use case would be after the user of the web browser requests to see certain time frames of data stored in camera's video files in its internal memory.  I would like to have p2p to avoid the NAT traversal issue (I think this can't be solved by HTTP solution?).

Comment: In that case, sure, WebRTC sounds like it could help you there.

Comment: Right, so the next concern is how difficult would it be to get a working (i.e. accurate) OSD display using WebRTC?   I assume the Browser itself won't support any OSD feature so I would have to rely on sending the OSD information through the Data Channel.  But if that were the case, how can I synchronize that DataChannel (OSD) with the video (Media Stream or some other DataChannel)?  Of course, other ideas to achieve the OSD in WebRTC are welcome.  That was just my initial idea but not sure if it was the most practical.

Comment: You shouldn't and couldn't depend on WebRTC doing the synchronisation for you, that'd have to be an application specific solution. E.g. if you can simply timestamp the OSD data, then the player can display the correct data based on the playing video's timestamp (now - start time). Not sure about this in practice, but worth a try.